# Importing from module deletes module (Google Colab)

Tags: python, python-import, google-colaboratory

`from some_module import SomeClass` --> *some_module.py* is now an empty .py file. Fixes itself after some time and re-uploading the module to Drive a number of times over.

Don't know steps to reproduce, behavior is inconsistent and spontaneous; different modules affected at different times. Nonetheless, my steps are:

1. Upload `some_module.py` to Google Drive
2. Mount Drive via `drive.mount('/content/drive')`
3. `%cd` into relevant directory
4. `from some_module import SomeClass`

Error below is yielded, and file contents are erased. -- How to prevent this behavior, or why does it occur?

---

**Update**: just observed `ind_rnn.py` *deleted shortly after upload* to Drive; all Colab sessions were off (terminated) at the time.

---

**Error trace**:

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-49a38c1853a2> in <module>()
     14 
---> 15 from ind_rnn import IndRNN_Block
     16 from se_res_net import _SqueezeExcite
     17 
ImportError: cannot import name 'IndRNN_Block'
```

(`IndRNN_Block` is, in fact, in `ind_rnn.py`)

---

**Erased file**:

[image]